# How do I populate a select tag when the page loads to only specific select tags?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function populateList(givenID)//givenID from the select tag
{
  var select = document.getElementById("givenID"),
  listData = ["1","2"];
                            
  for(var i = 0; i < listData.length; i++)
    //Loops through array and creates a new DOM node and appends array contents to the object
  {
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(listData[i]);
    option.appendChild(txt);
    option.setAttribute("value",listData[i]);
    select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
  }
}
```

```html
<body >    
    <select id="slt" whenpageloads="populateList">
         <!--When the page loads the select tag will be populated -->
        <option>
            default
        </option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Comment: use `<body onload="populateList('slt')"> `

Comment: Also, please move your `<script>` tag at the end of the body. Just above the `</body>`. It's not a good practice to write the script in the head when you're running it only after the body content has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call onload like Arun has mentioned on body load.

```
<body onload="populateList('slt')">
```

or

This will be better choice if you want to load more than one select boxes.

```
window.onload = function() {
   populateList('slt');
};
```

Apart from that there was one more mistake in your code, as givenID is variable.

```
var select = document.getElementById(givenID);
```

instead of

```
var select = document.getElementById("givenID");
```

```js
function populateList(givenID)//givenID from the select tag
{
  var select = document.getElementById(givenID);
  listData = ["1","2"];
                            
  for(var i = 0; i < listData.length; i++)
  {
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(listData[i]);
    option.appendChild(txt);
    option.setAttribute("value",listData[i]);
    select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
  }
}


window.onload = function() {
   populateList('slt');
};
```

```html
<body>    
    <select id="slt">
        <option>
            default
        </option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped greatly!!